# Select last child with specific element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use css pseudo class to select last child containing element with specific class?

Here is the code.

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="close">1</span></li>
    <li><span class="open">2</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">3</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">4</span></li>
    <li><span class="open">5</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">6</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">7</span></li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply specific styles on Number 5, means last **li** tag containing **span** tag with **open** class.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can't do this without javascript.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yes. But I would have preferred by CSS, if it is possible.

Comment: I already knew that. The problem is list content is dynamic, not static.

Comment: You can use `:last-child`  css selector 

e.g. `ul > li:last-child`

thus you can apply something on css and do not bother about javascript

Comment: I want to select last open class in list. not the last li element.

Comment: Its an entire different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using CSS only. You need to use JavaScript to do that.

Example: if you want to get LI which has the last `.close` element, use:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="close">1</span></li>
    <li><span class="open">2</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">3</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">4</span></li>
    <li><span class="open">5</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">6</span></li>
    <li><span class="close">7</span></li>
</ul>

<script>
var last_open_li = $('.open').last().parent();
var last_close_li = $('.close').last().parent();

last_open_li.css({background: 'green'});
last_close_li.css({background: 'red'});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yw7f4cfc/1/

Comment: It wont work. I want to apply css on number 5, no on number 6.

Comment: @Sanky: See my updated answer and fiddle in that. It works with last element of selected class.